# Adobe Flex Mobile 4.6 - Element positioning on iPad vs Android or BlackBerry seems off

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, blackberry, mobile

Forgive me if this is a stupid question. I'm a bit new to mobile development.

I'm trying to test out building an app with Adobe Flex 4.6, for iPad, Android, and BlackBerry PlayBook devices.

I just built a real quick and dirty 'Hello World!' app to start with. I placed an image, a button, and a textbox on the page, making them all centered. I set the application DPI to 160.

Now when I ran the app on my PlayBook, everything looks fine and awesome. I'm going to get an iPad from a co-worker to test, but I tested it on another developer's iPod Touch, and the app did not scale well at all. The positioning of the image and textbox are off, and the textbox was even over top of the image a bit.

I ran the Flash emulator a couple of times to simulate a Galaxy Tab 10.1, and the elements looked okay, but were off center due to the larger screen size. So the app is not scaling at all.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<s:Label x="323" y="365" width="377" height="40" fontSize="36" text=""     
    textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" id="label1" />
<s:TextInput id="textbox1" x="365" y="227"/>
<s:Button id="button" x="433" y="289" width="159" label="Button"
          click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I've found that using the applicationDPI causes more issues than it solves when it comes to layout.  I strongly suggest not using it. Also, lots of oddities in the simulator that do not exhibit on actual devices; so avoid that if possible.

Comment: Code snippet added. I removed some of the code that isn't relevant, but that is the jist of it.

Comment: +1 for adding the code snippet.  With Absolute, hard coded, positioning; I don't think you can assume your content will be centered on different device screens.

Comment: Yeah, when I read my own code after posting it, that thought sort of occurred to me. Sort of a "why in the hell would I do it that way?" moment. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your application center in all resolutions you don't have to use absolute coordinates. You need to use layouts. Like this for example:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:Label width="377" height="40" fontSize="36" text=""     
             textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" id="label1" />
    <s:TextInput id="textbox1" />
    <s:Button id="button" width="159" label="Button"
              click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: You are right that using layouts should be preferred. But from my understanding absolute coordinates should also work if you set the `applicationDpi` property. Do i get something wrong here?

Comment: @micha You're understanding is correct as per the documentation of ApplicationDPI; however it has caused me all sorts of layout issues in mobile apps; so I don't recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks, Art and Jeffry. I'll try it that way and report back.

Comment: Thanks so much, Art! That worked like a charm! I still need to test it on a real device, but so far it looks good when Flash Builder simulates a device.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com How do you manage the layouts without doing a lot of manual calculations in the code?

Comment: @ScottA For the most part, layouts that you want to be flexible are all manual calculations; relative to the last item you just placed.  It can be tedious (compared to throwing everything in a VGroup or HGroup.  But, when you write the formula once; it usually scales easy / without issues.  Put the calculations in updateDisplayList() or layoutContents() depending on the class you're extending